minecraft aternos powerranks tablist code
ive been trying to code the tablist in the plugin powerranks so it shows the name of my server, and lists the players by ranks and abc order, i did the part that shows the server name, i added this part for the abc order and listed by ranks part, and it stopped working (here is the code i added)
scoreboard-teams: enabled: true enable-collisons: true invisible-nametags: false anti-overrides: true sorting-types: - "RANKS:Owner,Admin,Hitone_Twitch,Nacho++,Nacho" - "PLACEHOLDER_A_TO_Z:%player%"
anyone knows how to fix?
i tried following a tutorial from youtube, and he showed some parts but he didnt show the entire way of doing it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Read the documentation.
